# Chrome 32 can't display Asian characters in tab title

Tags: google-chrome

Today I updated to Chrome 32 on Ubuntu 12.04, but tab title can't display Asian characters correctly, it displays typo instead. It works fine on Windows.
I've fired a bug for chromium project, however I still want to know if this is just for me or a common problem.

When I type "search" in Google, tab title shows:
[image]
When I type "検索", it shows:[image].

Can anyone reproduce this? In fact, I would love to fix this by myself but I may need some help on where I can find the code related to displaying tab title, the whole chromium code repository is just too big...

Comment: A better way to bring a bug to the attention of Chromium developers is via the bug tracker, see http://crbug.com/new and http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines. Since you've already done that, what the reason for posting here? Seeking confirmation?

Comment: @RobW kind of... On the other hand, if anyone can provide some instructions on where I can find related code/module, that'll be awesome.

Comment: I think that you will have more success by asking this question on the chromium-dev mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev